# could not determine generated file path for core data (Xcode 8, swift 3)

Tags: swift3, xcode8

How do you resolve this issue?

[image of message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtAX5.png)

(Black lines are to hide my username and project name)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the path of your .momd file once. According to image you've provided, `/Users/.../Library/Mobile Documents/com~Apple~CloudDocs/.../MyModel.momd` is the path expected. But, it couldn't read the core-data file from that path. Please move your .momd file to that expected path and try building it again.

Answer (score 1):

I got "could not determine generated file path for core data" when I moved my Core Data Model to a different folder. Go to your project file. In your Build Phases tab locate the model under Compile Sources and remove it. Then press + to add it back but DO NOT select it from the list you see right away (does not update the file path). Instead select "Add Other" and go select it from it's new location. Then leave the defaults of "copy if needed". Clean your build folder and you're good to go.

In my case this left me with 2 models in my property pane. I deleted the old and dragged and dropped the new one into the correct Xcode group. And all was right with the world again. Hope this helps someone else out.